# Fatal Error kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: flutter

iam working on a fluuter app to view pdfs and i have added some dependencies but when i run the app it keep on show this error.
Launching lib\main.dart on Infinix X6511B in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':flutter_pdfview:generateDebugRFile'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_pdfview:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.30.
> Required by:
> project :flutter_pdfview > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.30.
> > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.5.30/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.30.
> > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.5.30/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.30.
> > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.5.30/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.30.
> > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.5.30/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

i have done flutter clean and rrerun the app but no solution. pls help

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue but in another scenario ... While using Groovy to read and modify files in Jenkins ... Anyways it looks like your POM files have a BOM marker ... What I mean is they have been saved in the format UTF-8 with BOM instead of plain UTF-8 format ... Try saving it again in the UTF-8 format and the error should go away.